# 403 error using jwt authentication in spring boot even when correct credentials are entered

Tags: spring-boot, authentication, jwt

I am entering the correct email and password for logging in on postman but still it shows 403 error. Ideally if the email and password are found in the database the user should be authenticated and not see 403 response. On debugging I found that successful authentication method never runs even when credentials are correct. I cannot figure out the issue. Below is the code

**WebSecurity.java**

```
package com.org.security;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;


import com.org.service.UserService;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        private final UserService userDetailsService;
        private final BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

        public WebSecurity(UserService userDetailsService, BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder) {
            this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
            this.bCryptPasswordEncoder = bCryptPasswordEncoder;
        }
    
        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
            .cors().and()
            .csrf().disable();
            http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, SecurityConstants.SIGN_UP_URL)
            .permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated().and().addFilter(getAuthenticationFilter());
            
            
            http.headers().frameOptions().disable();
        }
        
        protected AuthenticationFilter getAuthenticationFilter() throws Exception {
            final AuthenticationFilter filter = new AuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager());
            filter.setFilterProcessesUrl("/users/login");
            return filter;
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
        }

}
```

**AuthenticationFilter.java**

```
package com.org.security;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;

import com.org.SpringApplicationContext;
import com.org.service.UserService;
import com.org.shared.dto.UserDto;
import com.org.ui.model.request.UserLoginRequestModel;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts;
import io.jsonwebtoken.SignatureAlgorithm;

public class AuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {

    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    
    

    public AuthenticationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        
        this.authenticationManager=authenticationManager;
            
    }

    //this method will be trigerred when authenticating a user from his mail and password
    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest req,
                                                HttpServletResponse res) throws AuthenticationException {
        try {
            //try block code will find the user and authenticate it
            
            //this will use the email and password in userLoginModel to authenticate
            //it will authenticate on the basis of email,password if found in the database a new function will be called
            UserLoginRequestModel creds = new ObjectMapper()
                    .readValue(req.getInputStream(), UserLoginRequestModel.class);
            
            return authenticationManager.authenticate(
                    new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken( 
                            creds.getEmail(),
                            creds.getPassword(),
                            new ArrayList<>())
            );   
            
          
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
       
    }
    //this runs on successfull authentication
    
     @Override
        protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest req,
                                                HttpServletResponse res,
                                                FilterChain chain,
                                                Authentication auth) throws IOException, ServletException {
            
            String userName = ((User) auth.getPrincipal()).getUsername();  
            
            String token = Jwts.builder()
                    .setSubject(userName)
                    .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + SecurityConstants.EXPIRATION_TIME))
                    .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, SecurityConstants.TOKEN_SECRET )
                    .compact();
            UserService userService = (UserService)SpringApplicationContext.getBean("userServiceImpl");
            UserDto userDto = userService.getUser(userName);
            
            res.addHeader(SecurityConstants.HEADER_STRING, SecurityConstants.TOKEN_PREFIX + token);
            res.addHeader("UserID", userDto.getUserId());

        }  

    }
```

**SecurityConstants**

```
package com.org.security;

public class SecurityConstants {

    
    
    public static final long EXPIRATION_TIME = 864000000; 
    public static final String TOKEN_PREFIX = "Bearer ";
    public static final String HEADER_STRING = "Authorization";
    public static final String SIGN_UP_URL = "/users";
    public static final String TOKEN_SECRET = "k";
}
```

Postman 403 error

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NM32Q.png

**UserLoginRequestModel**

```
package com.org.ui.model.request;

public class UserLoginRequestModel {

    private String email;
    private String password;

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

}
```

Comment: The issue seems to be in "com.org.ui.model.request.UserLoginRequestModel" class. What are the parameter names used in login form. is it email/password or username/password?

Comment: Can you please see for any issues in UserLoginRequestModel

Comment: Can you print/log creds after retrieval from request

Comment: creds is returning this-  com.org.ui.model.request.UserLoginRequestModel@1f078ab6  but the try block in attemptAuthentication returns null

Comment: Any solution for this??